# Two axis title in the same axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, axis

I have a vector x with two units. The initial part is in minutes and the final part in hours. Then, I need to plot y as a function of this x, but differentiating the units. It's a bit confusing, so I drew this chart below to give you an idea of what I need. Part of the data is in minutes and the other part is in hours and I need to plot both on the same graph. On the same graph as y(x).
The imagem below shows two titles to x-axis.

I have been trying to use matplotlib.pyplot but still no success. I'm hoping for some way to better manipulate the axis informations.

[Graph with a x-axis title for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6SQw.png)

Comment: (1) Please share a simple example code showing what you have tried. (2) Why do they need to be on the same plot? Why not plot them on separate plots and butt them together?

Comment: @jared Unfortunately, I really need to plot this data in the same graph. are data on the concentration of a reactant. this concentration is initially measured first in minutes, then it is measured in hours. And I don't have any code implemented for this, not even initial. Because I haven't been able to find anything like this on the internet yet.

Comment: @PauloGabrielFerreiradeAzev it'd be much better to use two subplots with no space between them, removing the entire y-axis from the rightmost subplot. The end result will appear to be one graph.

Comment: that would be a great idea @BigBen. I'll try something like that. Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is what @jared meant by "butt them together" :-)

Comment: oow yesss.. I'm sorry @jared I understand what you mean now hehehe thanks anyway

Comment: @BigBen Yes, that is what I was saying.

Comment: Can I be so bold as to suggest you may not really want to do this?  Rather, if your reaction has a lot of variation early on and less as time goes on, `semiologx` with all your data in units of minutes or hours would be a more usual way to show this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.